# Buscar numeros repetidos c

Tags: array, c

tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Dada una matriz cuadrada de números enteros comprendidos entre 1 y 100 escribir un algo-
ritmo que detecte todos los números que están repetidos y los reemplace por cero, indicando
cuántos hay sin repetir

yo lo intenté hacer así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C 3

int main( void ) {
  int matrizA[C][C];
  int i;
  int j;
  int v;
  char encontrado;
  int false;
  int true;

  v = matrizA[i][j];

  for( i = 1; i < C ; i++ ) {
    for( j = 1; j < C ; j++ ){
      printf( "\nintroduzca cada numero %d de la matriz cuadrada ", matrizA[i][j] );
      scanf( "%d", &matrizA[i][j] );
    }
    encontrado = false;

    for( i = 1; ( i < C ) && !encontrado; i++ ) {
      for( j = 1; ( j < C ) && !encontrado; j++ ) {
        if( matrizA[i][j] == v )
          encontrado = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

¿cómo véis el código?, es que al ejecutar me sale "Error del bus (`core' generado)"

Gracias

Comment: Revisa los mensajes al compilar. Cualquier compilador medianamente moderno te mostrará un montón de *warnings* de cosas que, aunque compila, parecen estar mal. Desde luego, no te fies que el hecho de que el programa compile signifique que está bien, C es notoriamente famoso por compilar casi cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Hola Robert Bienvenido.

mira los errores que veo en tu código son los siguientes, primero veo que asignas a V el valor de una variable que aun no has inicializado, pudiéndole dar cualquier valor, estos son errores de lógica, por otro lado el ciclo  for debes iniciarlo en `i = 0` y en `j = 0` si lo quieres usar como indice de arrays, finalmente si quieres recorrer la matriz buscando los repetidos yo recomiendo recorrer la matriz una vez por cada elemento, tal vez haya una solución mejor pero esta me sirvió. 
Saludos

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define C 3


 int main (void) {

  int matrizA[C][C];


  int i;
  int j;

  int v;
  char encontrado;
  int false;
  int true;


   //v = matrizA[i][j];
    //printf("El valor de v es %d, el valor de i es %d, y el valor de j es %d\n", v,i,j);
    /*
    * El array debes iniciarlo en 0 las posiciones de memoria van de 0 a 2 si son 3
    */
    //for (i=1;i<C ;i++) 
    for ( i = 0; i < C; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            // para "llenar" la matriz 
            printf ("\nintroduzca el indice %d, %d de la matriz cuadrada ", i+1, j+1);
         // printf ("\nintroduzca cada numero %d de la matriz cuadrada ", matrizA[i][j]);
          scanf ("%d",&matrizA[i][j]);
        }                                    
    }

// la variable encontrado hace que nunca entre al loop
  //encontrado = false;
//¿con que comparamos la matriz?
    int k, h;
    for ( k = 0; k < C; k++)
    {
        for (h = 0; h < C; h++)
        {
            v = matrizA [k][h];
            encontrado = false;
            for (i = 0; i < C; i++) 
            {
                for (j=0; j < C; j++) 
                {

                    if (matrizA[i][j] == v && (k != i || h != j ) && matrizA[i][j]!= 0)
                    {
                        matrizA[i][j] = 0;
                        //printf("El valor de v es %d, el valor de i es %d, y el valor de j es %d\n", v,i,j);
                        encontrado = true;

                    }



                }
            }
            if (encontrado)
                matrizA [k][h] = 0;
        }
    }

    // mostrando la matriz
    for ( i = 0; i < C; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d ", matrizA[i][j]);
        }                                 
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```