# Funcion para buscar un numero repetido en una matriz

Tags: c, matriz, repetidos

intento implementar una función que dada una matriz 3x3 como parámetro, retorne 1, si se encuentra al menos, un numero repetido dentro de ella, o retorne 0 de ser los 9 números distintos

```
4 9 2              4 9 9
3 5 7              3 2 1
8 1 6              1 5 8

retorna 0          retorna 1
```

A continuación la función con la que intento realizar esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int repetido(int **matriz){
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
                for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
                    if(b != d && a != c){
                        if(matriz[a][b] == matriz [c][d]){
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

La funcion sin embargo, no funciona, no puedo encontrar el error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta repetida varias veces en C.
por favor leete las normas y utiliza el buscador antes de iniciar una pregunta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+matriz+numeros+repetidos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Buscar numeros repetidos c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57875/buscar-numeros-repetidos-c)

Comment: Porque tienes 4 bucles? Solo con dos bucles basta. Hasta con un bucle se lo puede hacer (usando el operador modulo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la declaracion de

```
int repetido(int **matriz)
```

por

```
int repetido(int matriz[3][3])
```

Y el la comparacion cambiarla por

```
if(a != c || b != d){ //La fila o columna son diferentes ...
    if(matriz[a][b] == matriz [c][d]){ //... pero contienen el mismo valor
        return 1;
    }
}
```

en la que se evalúa que Si [a][b] es una posición diferente a [b][d] y contienen un mismo valor se devuelve 1 (esta repetido el valor dentro de la matriz)

Lo probé con el escenario de la pregunta:

```
int matriz1[3][3] = {
    {4,9,2},
    {3,5,7},
    {8,1,6}
};

int matriz2[3][3] = {
    {4,9,9},
    {3,2,1},
    {1,5,8}
};    

int r1, r2;
r1 = repetido(matriz1);
r2 = repetido(matriz2);
```